# How does one make a self-contained package / library of functions

Tags: octave

I am writing some support code in the common subset of Matlab/Octave, which comes in the form of a bunch of functions. Let's call it a package.

I want to be able to organize the package, i.e.,

1. put all the relevant function files in a single place, where users
   are not supposed to store their code;
2. have some internal organization ('subpackages');
3. prevent namespace pollution;
4. have some mechanism for user code to 'import' parts of the package;
5. I don't necessarily want all functions I provide to be
   visible from user clients.

On the Matlab side of things, this functionality is pretty much provided by package directories and the 'import' mechanism. This functionality doesn't appear to be available in Octave though (as of 3.6.1).

Given that, I wonder what options remain for organizing my support code package in Octave.

The option of putting everything in a directory and just have the user code do an ADDPATH feels rather unrefined, and doesn't give the level of control I want -- it only addresses point #1 of the list above.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Creating-Packages.html) and examples in [OctaveForge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/). Just browse the SVN.

Also there are personal packages all around. For example [this one](https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/ailab/people/carbajal/DRD/drd.html)

Happy coding!